# Minimal requirements for Corona SDK

Tags: coronasdk

What is minimal requirements for Android device for use Corona SDK???

I'm trying do run test app on Huawei SONIC - error force close;
on Sony Ericsson Live with Walkman - all correct.
The version android on this devices is 2.3.4

Some ideas or links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about your specific issue as that could be a bug in Corona, a bug in what you are doing or just the device itself but check out this link http://producerism.com/blog/where-corona-sdk-falls-flat/ - it has a lot of info on coronas downfalls and might show you something useful for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out by experience that there is at least one major thing to consider, especially if your app runs in the simulator, but not on your device. The simulator appears to not be case sensitive, but your device (phone/tablet) probably is case sensitive. Check any files you are using to make sure they are not mixed case. For example, myimage.png or myimage.PNG will both work on the simulator if it is coded as myimage.png in your lua code, but will install on your device, but fail to execute and usually force close when you touch the screen, or hit the back button several times.

Answer (score 0):

Android devices should have :

1. Android OS 2.2+
2. ARMV7 architecture devices.

If you have device that has above specification then only you can run your **CORONA** application on the device.